# Rails Tutorial: Lesson 3 Adding Static 'About' Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm completing Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial and am "3.2.2 - Adding a Page".

When trying to `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` I get the following error even though I've done everything according to the tutorial (all the pages should be in place etc.):

```
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/c
onfig/routes.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.14/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.14/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from C:in `execute_if_updated'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top
 (required)>'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `requir
e'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (
required)>'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.
rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.
rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

Here are the pages that (to my understanding) are required to make this work, and before adding these pages there were no errors:

**app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb**

```
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>
  The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  is a project to make a book and screencasts to teach web development
  with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>. This
  is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

**app/controller/static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"
  get "static_pages/about"
  .
  .
  .
end
```

**spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the content 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      page.should have_content('Help')
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do

    it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      page.should have_content('About Us')
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first line of your stack trace, it looks like you're explicitly including the vertical ellipses. I suspect the tutorial author wasn't intending for the '...' to be included – more to signify that there may be additional lines between the three static page routes and the end of the `routes.draw` block.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I thought the '...' was there in earlier examples and worked.